# How to get next pages in load more django

Tags: ajax, django, python-3.x

I get data using ajax with button load more, and if it's not have next pages, it will render "all data has been displayed"

index.html

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div id="display-data">
        <span id="loading-help">Loading data. . .</span>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
  var page = 1
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("{% url 'account:profile' %}?param=get_data&page="+page, 
    function(data){
        $("#display-data").append(data)
        $("#loading-help").remove()
        page++
    })
</script>
```

data-ajax.html

```
{% for data in datas %}
<div class="list-trx-data">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12 data-date"> 
            {{data.get_formatted_date}}</div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-12 data-name">
                <a href="#">{{data.get_data}}</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-8 data-amount"> 
            {{data.get_formatted_amount}}</div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-4 ">
                <div class="data-progress">
                    <div class="pg-bar" style="width: 
                {{data.get_data.get_progress_str}}"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% if datas.has_other_pages %}
  {% if datas.has_next %}
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-ghost btn-block mt-2" 
  id="load-more-btn">Load More</a>
  {% else %}
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-ghost btn-block mt-2" 
  id="load-more-btn">All data has been displayed</a>
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
<script>
 $("#load-more-btn").click(function(){
        $.get("{% url 'account:profile' %}?param=get_data&page="+page, 
        function(data){
            $("#display-data").append(data)
            page++
        })
    })
</script>
```

I have try it but it's render all button
[before click load more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMXhR.png)

[after click load more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJjwy.png)

how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't place javascript in the `data-ajax.html`. All the javascript code should be placed in `index.html`, where all the logics need to be implemented. If there is not other data, `data-ajax.html` returned should be empty.

> data-ajax.html

```
{% for data in datas %}
<div class="list-trx-data">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12 data-date"> 
            {{data.get_formatted_date}}</div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-12 data-name">
                <a href="#">{{data.get_data}}</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-8 data-amount"> 
            {{data.get_formatted_amount}}</div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-4 ">
                <div class="data-progress">
                    <div class="pg-bar" style="width: 
                {{data.get_data.get_progress_str}}"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% if datas.has_other_pages %}
  {% if datas.has_next %}
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-ghost btn-block mt-2" 
  id="load-more-btn">Load More</a>
{% endif %}
```

In your `index.html`, check if ajax call returned anything, if not, then change button text, else, remove the button element, since your `data-ajax.html` already has button based on `{% if datas.has_other_pages %}`.

> index.html

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div id="display-data">
        <span id="loading-help">Loading data. . .</span>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var page = 1;  //page defined in $(document).ready()

    function getData(){
      $.get("{% url 'account:profile' %}?param=get_data&page="+page, function(data){
          $("#loading-help").remove();
          if (data){
            // data was received
            $("#loading-help").remove();
            $("#load-more-btn").remove();  # remove the load button if data is there.
            $("#display-data").append(data);
            page++;
          } else {
             $("#load-more-btn").text("All data has been displayed");  # else, change button text.
          }
        });
    }

    getData();  //Load data for the first time.
    $("#load-more-btn").click(function(){
        getData();  //Load data on button click.
    });

</script>
```

Comment: when the button is clicked it does not display other data

Comment: can you be more specific as to what exactly is the issue you are facing?

Comment: i have try your code, and it's render ui perfectly but when button load more has click it's can't get next page.

Comment: does `getData` work? what is the data returned by the api? what is the value of `page`? you need some debugging as to what is happening.

Comment: if i put button load more in data-ajax.html, getData doesn't work. but if i put the button in index.html getData work perfectly but wording doesn't change

Comment: exactly, there might be some bug in the js code. keep all the js code in `index.html`, and debug it step by step. check the `data` returned by the api if there is not data. check why the changing of text doesn't work.

Comment: when i console.log (data), it's return data-ajax.html. it seems like data is always true

Comment: so, check what it is sending, and try to send empty response in `data-ajax.html` if no data is there.

Comment: if data-ajax.html is empty, button load more not show, because it is set to display:none